# C# Execution Loop

Tags: c#, process

I have just created a small program, nothing fancy, in C# that opens an rdp file. It then goes into an infinite loop and keeps checking if mstsc is running, if it is then it does nothing, if it isn't (user has closed the session), it re - opens. I ran the code below and it hammered my CPU and then shortly after blue screened, minidump says it was because "This indicates that an exception happened while executing a routine that transitions from non-privileged code to privileged code."

Not sure what this means, but any ideas what is wrong with this code?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    RDP();
    for (int i = 1; i > 0; i++)
    {
        foreach (Process clsProcess in Process.GetProcesses())
        {
            if (clsProcess.ProcessName.Contains("mstsc.exe"))
            {
            }
            else
            {
                RDP();
            }
        }
    }
}

private static void RDP()
{
    Process rdp = new Process();
    rdp.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("C:\\Alistair\\Default.rdp");
    rdp.Start();
}
```

**Update:** I thought that the processing power needed for the infinite loop might have been to blame but I tried looping for 5 times but same result.

Comment: Define "Blue screened".  Did this blue-screen your entire PC?

Comment: Yeah it gave me the blue screen of death, Valamas worked out what was causing it and Cody fixed it, see answers below

Comment: What operating system was this on?  You might want to consider submitting a bug report to Microsoft if this is reproducible.

Comment: It's Windows 7 x64, I think I was just creating too many processes and the CPU just couldn't keep up, Cody refinement fixed it, I think the pause made a big difference as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    RDP();
    while(true)
    {
        if(Process.GetProcessesByName("mstsc").Length == 0)
            RDP();
        Thread.sleep(300); // Use any value which is confortable with you're request
    }
}

private static void RDP()
{
    Process rdp = new Process();
    rdp.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("C:\\Alistair\\Default.rdp");
    rdp.Start();
}
```

Here is a portion of code optimised, and it will not hang your CPU at 100 %.

What you can do is to check the Process event onExit(not sure), or just check `rdp.HasExited` if true than restart.

Comment: Thanks thats definitely solved the CPU problem but it is still continuing to open the rdp file even though the mstsc process is running

Comment: @Bali C try it now ,it should work because testing with Process.ProcessName you should use only the process Name without .exe Extension

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if Process.GetProcesses(), since it is a method, gets a fresh list of processes. Maybe try storing the result in a list first.

Comment: Yeah maybe, but how would I keep the list updated, wouldn't it keep the same processes that it reads the first loop around?

Comment: Keep the same code. Just could keep a list of processes you have read. Use ProcessID as the key to know if the process has been read.

Answer (score 0):

Try wait for process to start. It cannot start immidiatly even in theory.

Second. You check if process is running is incorrect, resulting in ~100 calls to RDP()

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

class Watchdog 
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while(true) {
            if (!IsRdpRunning())
                RunRdp();
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    private static void RunRdp()
    {
        Process rdp = new Process();
        rdp.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Alistair\Default.rdp");
        rdp.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
    }

    private static bool IsRdpRunning()
    {
            foreach (Process clsProcess in Process.GetProcesses())
            {
                if (clsProcess.ProcessName.Contains("mstsc"))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
    }
}
```